# Which Keys are used to move while using KeyNavigatorBehavior? How do I set them?

Tags: java, java-3d

I've learned something about Java3D and I wondered how to move around the Camera using keystrokes. I've found the KeyNavigatorBehavior and set it up, just there is no Key doing anything. How do I use this Behavior properly?

Here I got my method setting the Behavior:

```
protected BranchGroup buildViewBranch(Canvas3D c) {

        BranchGroup viewBranch = new BranchGroup();
        Transform3D viewXfm = new Transform3D();

        viewXfm.set(new Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f));

        TransformGroup viewXfmGroup = new TransformGroup(viewXfm);

        viewXfmGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
        viewXfmGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);

        BoundingSphere movingBounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0,0.0), 100.0);

        BoundingLeaf boundLeaf = new BoundingLeaf(movingBounds);
        ViewPlatform myViewPlatform = new ViewPlatform();

        viewXfmGroup.addChild(boundLeaf);

        PhysicalBody myBody = new PhysicalBody();
        PhysicalEnvironment myEnvironment = new PhysicalEnvironment();

        viewXfmGroup.addChild(myViewPlatform);
        viewBranch.addChild(viewXfmGroup);

        View myView = new View();

        myView.addCanvas3D(c);
        myView.attachViewPlatform(myViewPlatform);
        myView.setPhysicalBody(myBody);
        myView.setPhysicalEnvironment(myEnvironment);

        KeyNavigatorBehavior keyNav = new KeyNavigatorBehavior(viewXfmGroup);

        keyNav.setSchedulingBounds(movingBounds);
        viewBranch.addChild(keyNav);

        return viewBranch;

    }
```

Here are the lines setting the VirtualUniverse:

```
        group = new BranchGroup();

        VirtualUniverse universe = new VirtualUniverse();

        Locale locale = new Locale(universe);
        locale.addBranchGraph(this.buildViewBranch(canvas));
        locale.addBranchGraph(group);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

You have to activate KeyboardMouse (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Num</kbd>) and deactivate numlock:

Keys are: arrows + page up/down (also on the numlock)